# Why is the contained element name not validated when validating an xml file against multiple xsd files using eclipse?

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd, schema

I am authoring xml schemas using eclipse and I have small problem with validation.

I have two schemas and an xml file.

Main.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Main"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Main"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <complexType name="mainType">
        <sequence>
            <any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <element name="main" type="tns:mainType" />
</schema
```

Sub.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Sub"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Sub"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <complexType name="subType">
        <attribute name="name" type="string"
            use="required" />
    </complexType>

    <element name="sub" type="tns:subType" />
</schema>
```

Sample.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:main xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Main"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:sub="http://www.example.org/Sub"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.example.org/Main Main.xsd 
        http://www.example.org/Sub Sub.xsd">
    <sub:sub name="test" />
</tns:main>
```

If I change the name attribute of the sub element then the validation fails as expected:

[image: Validation fails as expected]

But if I change the element name of the sub element then the validation succeeds:

[image: Validation succeeds]

I expected this validation to fail too. What is it not?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because this definition of lax from the XML Schema Definition:

> lax: If the item has a uniquely determined declaration available, it
>   must be ·valid· with respect to that declaration, that is, ·validate·
>   if you can, don't worry if you can't.

In other words, since there is no declaration for a `<sub:subx>` element available, it's valid.